# Limiting a Neo4j cypher query results by sum of relationship property

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Is there a way to limit a cypher query by the sum of a relationship property?

I'm trying to create a cypher query that returns nodes that are within a distance of 100 of the start node.  All the relationships have a distance set, the sum of all the distances in a path is the total distance from the start node.

If the WHERE clause could handle aggregate functions what I'm looking for might look like this

```
START n=node(1)
MATCH path = n-[rel:street*]-x
WHERE SUM( rel.distance ) < 100
RETURN x
```

Is there a way that I can sum the distances of the relationships in the path for the where clause?

Answer (score 2):

I've come across the same problem recently. In more recent versions of neo4j this was solved by the *extract* and *reduce* clauses. You could write:

```
START n=node(1)
MATCH path = (n)-[rel:street*..100]-(x)
WITH extract(x in rel | x.distance) as distances, x
WITH reduce(res = 0, x in rs | res + x) as distance, x
WHERE distance <100
RETURN x
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure, what you want to do is like a having in a SQL query.

In cypher you can chain query segments and use the results of previous parts in the next part by using `WITH`, see the [manual](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/query-with.html).

For your example one would assume:

```
START n=node(1)
MATCH n-[rel:street*]-x
WITH SUM(rel.distance) as distance
WHERE distance < 100
RETURN x
```

Unfortunately sum doesn't work with collections yet

So I tried to do it differently (for variable length paths):

```
START n=node(1)
MATCH n-[rel:street*]-x
WITH collect(rel.distance) as distances
WITH head(distances) + head(tail(distances)) + head(tail(tail(distances))) as distance
WHERE distance < 100
RETURN x
```

Unfortunately head of an empty list doesn't return `null` which could be `coalesce`d to `0` but just fails. So this approach would only work for fixed length paths, don't know if that's working for you.

Comment: I went this route as well but unfortunately the fixed path length doesn't work for me.

Comment: don't you have to put the return value x into the WITH statement?: ...WITH x, SUM(rel.distance) as distance .... RETURN x.

Comment: I've added a pull request with functionality to support this (waiting on feedback): https://github.com/neo4j/community/pull/878

Comment: @ddunlop Pull request accepted, see example syntax here if you can use 1.9-SNAPSHOT: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12587263/cypher-order-by-path-cost/12588013#12588013

Answer (score -1):

i dont know about a limitation in the WHERE clause, but you can simply specify it in the MATCH clause:

```
START n=node(1)
MATCH path = n-[rel:street*..100]-x
RETURN x
```

see http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/query-match.html#match-variable-length-relationships

Comment: This doesn't do what he wants. Distance is actually a property of the relationship.

Comment: i think this is what he wants. he just pictured the distance as a rel property, but he just wanted to get the number of paths.

Comment: This is not what I'm looking for, this query does not take distance, which is a numerical property of the relationship, into account.